# Turning on/off leds very fast. Will it do harm?

Tags: arduino, led

I am using an arduino board to controll a led strip. 3 transistor and 3 resistors are between the board and the leds. 1 for each color (RGB). I am using analogWrite to change the brightness.

But I wanted to make the leds even less bright, without adding another resistor. I figured out that when i turn them on and off very fast they will not flicker but they will appear to be less bright.

Will this harm the leds? Or is this ok to do? Do other people also use this trick?

Comment: LEDs can be turned on and off without damage at any frequency An Arduino can produce port pin changes down to perios around 1 uS and LEDs camn be switched at rates far above 1 MHz before you encounter any issues. Even at rates where phosphor output decay starts to matter you will not damage the LED.

Comment: When designing an induction cooker, with high frequencies and high currents then you need special components and a good design. But not for leds. Is analogWrite(1) to a PWM capable pin still too bright ? Then you need extra resistors. Some RGB leds have a controller inside, they require a digital control signal and they have often more steps than 255, thus allowing smoother and more dimmed brightness.

Comment: If it did the whole fibre-optic business would be out of work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the `analogWrite` function is already doing: turning the LED on and off rapidly is called pulse-width modulation (PWM), and it's the standard way of dimming LEDs. It's perfectly safe at any reasonable frequency.

Comment: Thanks, so when i use analogwrite to controll a transistor, the transistor also turns on and off very quickly?

Comment: @abanana Yes, this is documented in the Arduino reference guide at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

Comment: The ripple current factors in a bit.  Turning on and off an LED with no inductance is not a good thing.  It will not kill it, it will dim faster over time than a well regulated current.